# Flutter_Stripe Package not compatible with purchases_flutter ?- Result of updating to Flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, pubspec, revenuecat

I am getting the following version resolving error and I am wondering if anybody has an idea for a workaround?

Pub Spec

```
  purchases_flutter: ^3.10.0
  flutter_stripe: ^3.3.0
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
```

ERROR:

```
   Because purchases_flutter 3.10.0 depends on freezed_annotation ^1.1.0 and no versions of purchases_flutter match >3.10.0 <4.0.0, purchases_flutter ^3.10.0 requires freezed_annotation ^1.1.0.
So, because multiculturalapp depends on both purchases_flutter ^3.10.0 and freezed_annotation ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because multiculturalapp depends on both purchases_flutter ^3.10.0 and freezed_annotation ^2.1.0, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the error because `purchases_flutter` depends on version `^1.1.0` of `freezed_annotation`, which means it needs a version that is at least 1.1.0, but lower than 2.X.X.  However, you're specifying `freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0`, which means you're saying you need 2.1.0 or higher, but lower than 3.X.X.

There's no way to resolve that conflict, so you see the error.

Can you switch to `freezed_annotation: ^1.1.0`?

Comment: Hi Justin! Thank you for your answer, no actually I can not stay with freezer_annotation 1.1.0 because flutter_stripe needs at least 2.1.0